# Non-nullable instance field '_database' must be initialized

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, dart

I am trying to use a database form assets folder in my flutter app. I tried this code :

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static const _databaseName = "main.db";
  static const _databaseVersion = 1;

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _initDatabase(); // only initialize if not created already
    return _database;
  }

  _initDatabase() async {
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), _databaseName);

    if (!(await databaseExists(path))) {
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", _databaseName));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    }
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _databaseVersion);
  }
}
```

But the code is throwning this error at this code   `DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();`
error:
The non-nullable variable '_database' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression.

and at this code :
static Database _database;

```
Non-nullable instance field '_database' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field
```

i am new to flutter, i don't know what that means... please help me solve this :)

Comment: place late keyword at a starting for _database

Comment: @AmitSingh No! `late` generally should be used as a last resort.  You cannot check if a `late` variable has been initialized, and `_database` is initialized asynchronously.  This code clearly intends for `_database` to be nullable.  Instead change its declaration to ` static Database? _database;`.

Comment: Is someone going to actually answer this question? Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analyzer is complaining because you have `_database` as it is right now as non-null because you're using the type `Database` which means a value is guaranteed to be there... non-null. To make something nullable, which this is, you need to put a `?` behind the type e.g. `Database?`

```dart
static Database _database;
```

should be

```dart
static Database? _database;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try **late** keyword

```
late Database _database;
```

Comment: No, `late` should be a last resort.  See my comment to the question.

Comment: This isn't a `late` value! The `database` getter is "lazy loading" the `_database` value. `late` values are things that are guaranteed to be non-null because they're set in the body of a constructor.